# Run specific macro in word by using hyperlink from a webpage

Tags: vba, ms-word

Due to server rights I can not access the word object and can only starts word on the client by hyperlinking in asp, such as:

```
file:///Z:/Prosjekt/32637/LS_32637_PR_01_A.docm
```

However I would like to run a spefic macros with parameters, can I somehow do this?

```
file:///Z:/Prosjekt/32637/LS_32637_PR_01_A.docm?NewFile.NewFile,1,"Test"
```

Maybe it is possible to write an on open event that parses the `NewFile,1,"Test"` to call `NewFile.newFile(1,"test")`

But I am not sure how to do so. Any hint on how to solve it would be great.

Comment: It will be very difficult to get this working if there is a solution to this at all. However, it seems you prefer doing something with the document on the server anyway. Can you describe what actually should happen with the document?

Comment: FWIW it's not possible to pass parameters to a macro via command line. What you could do is write the information somewhere that the macro can then access. A webservice would be logical, but VBA would require a reference to a library in order to use it since that functionality is not built into VBA.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to create a textfile and then read this textfile on word_open command, if no text file exits then just proceed as normal.